# How to collect the Azure VM auto-shutdown time using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I need to collect the Azure VM auto-shutdown time using PowerShell, but don't know how to get to the necessary resource property so the auto-shutdown time is reflected.

I am getting the following output:

```
ID:  /subscriptions/12345/resourceGroups/W12RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/W12

Name                   ResourceGroupName ResourceType                   Location
----                   ----------------- ------------                   --------
shutdown-computevm-W12 W12RG             Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules eastus1
```

```
# Retrieve the resource group information
[array]$ResourceGroupArray = Get-AzureRMVm | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName, Name, VmId

foreach ($resourceGroup in $ResourceGroupArray){
    $targetResourceId = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -Name $resourceGroup.Name).Id
    $shutdownInformation = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules |  ft
    Write-Host "ID: " $targetResourceId
    $shutdownInformation
}
```

I need to collect the auto-shutdown time for the Azure VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `-Expandproperties` switch to `Get-AzureRMResource` to gain access the properties that contain the data you need. This will allow you to access `.Properties`, which will return an object with various other properties (`.dailyRecurrence` gives the shutdown time). The shutdown time appears to just be a string value of 4 numbers with the first two numbers representing the hour and last two being the minutes. So 6:30:45 AM would be 0630, and 11:45:55 PM would be 2345.

```
[array]$ResourceGroupArray = Get-AzureRMVm | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName, Name, VmId

foreach ($resourceGroup in $ResourceGroupArray){
    $targetResourceId = (Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -Name $resourceGroup.Name).Id
    $shutdownInformation = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules -Expandproperties).Properties
    Write-Host "ID: " $targetResourceId
    $shutdownInformation
}
```

I removed your `| ft` since it is generally not best practice to send data through the formater before storing the value. It will change your object and therefore change the properties. You then won't be able to reference those properties as expected later. If you want to display data that way, you can just append that to your lone `$shutdownInformation` line. In other words, send data through format-table at the time you want to output.